# How can I get created time of all likes of a post?

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'd like to get all created_times of all likes of a post.

Is there any way to get this? using Graph API or FQL??

Answer (score 4):

Per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/ There is no like time listed in the available columns

Also in the Graph API post object, the likes field is only an array of ids and name of the liker. There is no like time listed.

Comment: I found that in the **Activity Log** of user's facebook, we can see the time of like on facebook. But, if facebook api does not provide api for developers, it's impossible to get time of likes.